# Python 2.7 Method Resolution Order overrride

Tags: python, python-2.7, multiple-inheritance, method-resolution-order

I am having some problem using multiple inheritance in Python and can't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have three classes A,B,C defined as follows it does not work.

```
class A(object):
   def __init__(**kwargs):
     .
     .

class B(object):
   def __init__(**kwargs):
    # prepare a dictionary "options" with the options used to call A
    super(B,self).__init__(**options)

   def coolmethod(x):
      #some cool stuff
```

For A and B I don't have any problems.

I want to create a third class C that inherits both from A and B
so that I can the coolmethod defined in B, but would like to use the constructor defined in A.

Trying to define `class C(A,B)` does not work because the MRO is not defined.

But defining `class C(B,A)` does not allow me to use A.**init** rather than B.**init**.

How can I solve the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call A.__init__() directly instead of using super() in C:

```
class C(B,A):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        A.__init__(self, **kwargs)
```

Comment: thanks.. it was pretty easy.. I can't understand why the order in the class declaration matters though....

Comment: See my answer below for an explanation on the order.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(A, self).__init__(**kwargs)
```

if you expect multiple inheritance from A and something else. This way, `A.__init__` will always be called.

The order is important because of the way method resolution works in python. If you have C inherit from (A, B), it means that if you invoke a method on C that exists both on A and B, the one on A is selected (it has precedence). If you write `super(A, self).method` in class A, it means you want to extend functionality provided by `method`. Therefore, it would be strange to skip over one such extension if both A and B had such extensions and C inherited from both. That's why when you call `C.method`, it will execute `A.method`, which will call `B.method` when it invokes `super(A, self).method`. In other terms, it's as if A inherited from B for the purpose of method extension. This is different when C inherits from (B, A).

Note that `__init__`'s first argument should always be `self`, just like for every method.